# How do I use Unboxed Vectors?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement a ray data type using the Vector type found here: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Numeric_Haskell:_A_Vector_Tutorial#Importing_the_library

The Vector will only hold doubles, so I would like to use the Unboxed version of the Vector type.

Here is the code I am trying to compile:

```
module Main where

    import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as Vector

    data Ray = Ray Data.Vector.Unboxed Data.Vector.Unboxed
```

The error I get is

```
Not in scope: type constructor or class `Data.Vector.Unboxed'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The module `Data.Vector.Unboxed` exports a type constructor `Vector` which takes as an argument the type you want to store. Since you renamed this module to `Vector` as well, the qualified name for this type is `Vector.Vector`. Assuming you want two vectors of doubles, you should therefore use it like this:

```
data Ray = Ray (Vector.Vector Double) (Vector.Vector Double)
```

Answer (score 6):

Normally, when you import something, you do it like this:

```
import Data.Foo -- A module that contains "data Bar = Bar ..."

myfunction = Bar 3 2 4 -- Use Bar
```

As you can see, you can access all of the stuff in the `Data.Foo` module directly, as if you were writing code in that same module.

You can instead import something with qualification, which means that you must specify the full module "path" to the thing that you are referring to every time you access it:

```
import qualified Data.Foo -- A module that contains "data Bar = Bar ..."

myfunction = Data.Foo.Bar 3 2 4 -- Use Bar
```

Here, you must specify the full "path" to the data type that you're accessing, because the module has been imported as qualified.

There is another way to import something with qualification; you can specify an alias for the module "path" like so:

```
import qualified Data.Foo as Foo -- A module that contains "data Bar = Bar ..."

myfunction = Foo.Bar 3 2 4 -- Use Bar
```

We have renamed the `Data.Foo` part to simply `Foo`. This way, we can write `Foo.Bar` when referring to the data constructor.

You imported the module `Data.Vector.Unboxed` with the alias `Vector`. This means that when you want to access the `Vector` data type, you must use `Vector.Vector`. I'd recommend that you import vectors like this instead:

```
import Data.Vector.Unboxed (Vector)
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as Vector
```

This way, you import the `Vector` type directly, so that you can access it without any module qualifiers, but when you want to use `Vector` functions, you need to add the `Vector` prefix (For example `Vector.null ...`).